# UseExceptionHandler save context and redirect to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am just curios to know how this below piece of code works.

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

public class HomeController : Controller {
   public IActionResult Error() {
        // Im able to retrieve the error and the user context
        var ctx = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
   }
}
```

However If I have implemented the same using delegate

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(a => a.Run(async context => {
    context.Response.Redirect("/home/error");
}

public class HomeController : Controller {
   public IActionResult Error() {
        // I get null
        // What logic do I need to put to behave it like the above one
        var ctx = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
   }
}
```

I know it is because of 302 redirect but how does `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");`
 is able to do that, How it is able to re-execute the request with different controller. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, I have gone through the source code https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerExtensions.cs but not sure if I get it completely.

Comment: Did you try using fiddler and see what happens if you trigger the error ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari Thanks but could you please try and let me know what it outputs. I don't have access to fiddler it would be great if you can show me the behavior